# Fill data from Firebase in my empty arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I try to create a "single client" view. Each client has a prenom (first name) and a nom (last name). Actually, my application seems to know that there are two values for a client but these values do not appear..

My question: Why the data does not appear.

This is what I got for the URL LOCALHOST/#/clients/-JYvLztvmRIcT8ITKWl1

**Updated**: see live code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/0waQY6ny8TvgNZhz4DRW?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<p>Client: {{client}}</p>
<p>Clients: {{clients}}</p>
<p>Client.prenom: {{client.prenom}}</p>
```

**Generated HTML** (when I load the page)

```
Client: [{},{}]
Clients:
Client.prenom:
```

Controller (app.js code snippet)

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'accueil.html'
      }).
      when('/clients', {
        templateUrl: 'clients.html',
        controller: 'ClientsCtrl'
      }).
      when('/clients/:clientId', {
        templateUrl: 'client.html',
        controller: 'ClientSoloCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);

app.controller('ClientSoloCtrl', ClientSoloCtrl);
function ClientSoloCtrl ($scope, $firebase, $routeParams) {

  var clientId = $routeParams.clientId;
  var ref = new Firebase("https://crmfirebase.firebaseio.com/clients/"+clientId);
  $scope.client = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

  $scope.removeClient = function(client) {
    $scope.client.$remove(client);
  };

  $scope.addClient = function (client) {
    $scope.client.$add(client);
  };

  $scope.updateClient = function (client) {
    $scope.client.$save(client);
  };

}
```

Comment: Hi Lucien. Can you set up a reproduction of your problem on a site like jsFiddle or jsBin?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, let me do this and post back a URL.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Here it is http://plnkr.co/edit/0waQY6ny8TvgNZhz4DRW?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I go to your Plunkr, the list of clients populates correctly. That part is handled by `ClientsCtrl` and works the way I'd expect it.

When you then click one of the clients, navigation goes client.html and `ClientSoloCtrl`. There you're doing:

```
var clientId = $routeParams.clientId;
var ref = new Firebase("https://crmfirebase.firebaseio.com/clients/"+clientId);
$scope.client = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
```

Your mistake is in the last line. You're trying to bind a single object to the `$scope`, not an array. So you should be using `$asObject` instead of `$asArray` here.

```
var clientId = $routeParams.clientId;
var ref = new Firebase("https://crmfirebase.firebaseio.com/clients/"+clientId);
var client = $firebase(ref).$asObject();
client.$bindTo($scope, 'client');
```

That last line makes the (synchronized) client object available to the view by the name `client`, which is what you use in your view's HTML:

```
    <form class="form-inline" ng-submit="updateClient(client)">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Prénom" ng-model="client.prenom" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nom de famille" ng-model="client.nom" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Sauvegarder</button>
    </form>
```